# How to add Google Analytics Event Tracking to Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics

I have a standard implementation of a Bootstrap Accordion(Collapse) and am trying to track open click events in Google Analytics.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div id="headingOne" class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a href="#collapseOne" id="tab1" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"> 
       <span class="faq">What products do you offer? </span><span class="arrow"></span> 
      </a>
   </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Content..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using Google Tag Manager but cannot manage to get the trigger to fire.  I've tried every filter combination I can think of.

Anyone had luck with this?

Comment: did you look at this it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126924/trigger-a-bootstrap-collapsetoggle-via-an-event/17126960#17126960

Comment: How is your trigger configured? Which element is being clicked to trigger the collapse?